# Determine Visible Worksheet Area Size in Points

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to determine the visible worksheet area in points. So far, I have tried the `Application.Width`, but that gives me the entire area including the scroll bars, and likewise `Application.Height` includes the ribbon and horizontal scroll bar. What I need specifically is the size of only this viewable worksheet area.

Something I have tried so far is looking at the visible range. For example, if I can see A1 thru AA40, then I can use the code

```
 Debug.Print ws.Range("A1:AA40").Width
 Debug.Print ws.Range("A1:AA40").Height
```

The only problem with this is if I can see half of column AB and half of row 41, then I don't have the full size. Also, it is not adjustable if I decide to change the application window size to half the screen.

I have no need for converting into the number of pixels, I just need the point sizes. Does anyone know a way to get the visible area size, or at the very least how to resize a range to fit only this visible area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Windows` collection of `Application` and use the `Width` and `Height` properties of items of that collection. E.g.

```
Debug.Print Application.Windows(1).Width
Debug.Print Application.Windows(1).Height
```

You can also refer to `ActiveWindow` and get the properties from that as well.

Example:

[image]

Comment: That wound up giving me the dimensions of the application window still, so a line drawn diagonally from top left to bottom right ended up going off screen. HOWEVER, it DID lead me to the answer I needed. Just change `Width` to `UseableWidth` and likewise for height. That worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting follow up, when I tried a sample of this on one computer, it worked fine. On my other computer, I had to turn headings off in order to make it work right. Curious, but I didn't want headings displayed anyway in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Grid's dimensions:

?Activewindow.activepane.VisibleRange.Height, Activewindow.activepane.VisibleRange.Width

The above worked for me, returning the dimensions of only Excel's grid which could be seen on my screen- no scrollbars, no Ribbon, no formula bar - just cells displayed.